# Jasmine testing multiple spies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing a few tests for an Angular application, these are my first stab at unit tests for Angular using Jasmine. I'm having trouble structuring the test to cater for the various scenarios inside the function (namely the if statement and callbacks).

Here's my $scope function, which takes an Object as an argument, and if that object has an `id`, then it updates the object (as it'll already exist), otherwise it creates a new report and pushes to the backend using the `CRUD` service.

```
$scope.saveReport = function (report) {
  if (report.id) {
    CRUD.update(report, function (data) {
      Notify.success($scope, 'Report updated!');
    });
  } else {
    CRUD.create(report, function (data) {
      $scope.report = data;
      Notify.success($scope, 'Report successfully created!');
    });
  }
};
```

My test so far passes in a fake Object with an `id` so it'll trigger the `CRUD.update` method, which I then check is called.

```
describe('$scope.saveReport', function () {
  var reports, testReport;
  beforeEach(function () {
    testReport = {
      "id": "123456789",
      "name": "test"
    };
    spyOn(CRUD, 'update');
    $scope.saveReport(testReport);
  });
  it('should call CRUD factory and update', function () {
    expect(CRUD.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testReport, jasmine.any(Function));
  });
});
```

I understand Jasmine doesn't allow multiple spies, but I want to be able to somehow test for the if condition, and run a mock test for when the Object *doesn't* pass in an Object too:

```
describe('$scope.saveReport', function () {
  var reports, testReport;
  beforeEach(function () {
    testReport = {
      "id": "123456789",
      "name": "test"
    };
    testReportNoId = {
      "name": "test"
    };
    spyOn(CRUD, 'update');
    spyOn(CRUD, 'create'); // TEST FOR CREATE (NoId)
    spyOn(Notify, 'success');
    $scope.saveReport(testReport);
    $scope.saveReport(testReportNoId); // TEST FOR NO ID
  });
  it('should call CRUD factory and update', function () {
    expect(CRUD.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testReport, jasmine.any(Function));
    // UNSURE ON THIS PART TOO
  });
});
```

I've read things about using the `.andCallFake()` method, but I could not see how this could work with my setup. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the alternative syntax `jasmine.createSpy()` ?

Comment: Jasmine 2 added ability to reset spies during tests, might that give what you need?  In the prior version, i just created separate tests for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should decide on what you need to test first. If you want to test simply that update is called when id exists or create is called when it does not then you should just structure the it function with those conditions. The before each is the wrong place for some of those things.

```
it('should call CRUD factory and update', function () {
    spyOn(CRUD, 'update');
    $scope.saveReport(testReport);
    expect(CRUD.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testReport, jasmine.any(Function));
});
it('should call CRUD create', function() {
    spyOn(CRUD, 'create');
    $scope.saveReport(testReportNoId); // TEST FOR NO ID
    expect(CRUD.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testReport, jasmine.any(Function));
});
```

Only put things in the before each that you actually should do before each test.

Hope this helped!